# kss-node multiple markup on page?

Tags: sass, gulp, pug, kss

is there a way so show multiple markup on a page in kss-node? Like a overview page?

Normal:

```
// Whatever 
//
// Lets show Whatever 
//
// Markup: atoms/2.01.whatever/_2.01.1.whatever.html
//
// Whatever 2.01
@import "2.01.1.whatever";
```

What i want is like:

```
// Whatever 
//
// Lets show Whatever 
//
// Markup: atoms/2.01.whatever/_2.01.1.whatever.html
// Markup: atoms/2.01.2.whatever2/_2.01.2.whatever2.html
//
// Whatever 2.01
@import "2.01.1.whatever";
@import "2.01.2.whatever2.html";
```

The output should show 2 Markup sections, but this wont work. Always show 1 Markup.

Any idea here?

I testet:

```
// Whatever 
//
// Lets show Whatever 
//
// Markup: atoms/2.01.whatever/_2.01.1.whatever.html
// Markup: atoms/2.01.2.whatever2/_2.01.2.whatever2.html
//
// Whatever 2.01
@import "2.01.1.whatever";
@import "2.01.2.whatever2.html";
```

or

```
// Whatever 
//
// Lets show Whatever 
//
// Markup: atoms/2.01.whatever/_2.01.1.whatever.html
//
// Whatever 2.01
@import "2.01.1.whatever";
//
// Whatever2
//
// Lets show Whatever 2
//
// Markup: atoms/2.01.2.whatever2/_2.01.2.whatever2.html
@import "2.01.2.whatever2.html";
```

But nothing is working here :-(

Comment: What does this question have to do with Pug?